# How to aggregate rows based on matching values in several columns?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, datatable

Say I have the following

```
d = {'A': [True,False,True,True,False,False],'B': ["Blue","Yellow","Blue","Red","Green","Yellow"], 
'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

      A       B   C

0   True    Blue  1

1  False  Yellow  2

2   True    Blue  3

3   True     Red  4

4  False   Green  5

5  False  Yellow  6
```

I want to aggregate the rows which have equivalent values for both A and B, summing on C. This will result in a new DataFrame with four rows. As an example, consider rows 0 and 2. Both rows have equal values for A and equal values for B. Since the rows have equal values for A and B, I want them to be aggregated into a single row with the value of C being updated to the sum of C for both of them. The new observation that would represent rows 0 and 2 would be (True, Blue, 4).

NOTE:
I want to apply the strategy proposed as a solution to a large dataset where it would not be practical to aggregate based on hard-coded conditionals (ie if A==x and B==y, then aggregate with the sum of C) because the values of x and values of y could have hundreds or thousands of different possible values.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.groupby()` as:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()
```

This takes all unique combinations of column 'A' and 'B' and sums the rest of the columns, in this case, 'C'.

Comment: That appears to work but it seems to make some of the A column values disappear. how do i prevent that? Also how does the above differ from df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum() ? the output seems slightly different when I use this command

Comment: I am unsure how that would happen, could you elaborate or give an example? `df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum() ` simply specifies which column you want to sum, thus returns a Pandas `Series` as a result, instead of a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @math4545454 `df['C'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).transform(sum)`